# How to solve this bad key error in flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to enter values in form and fetch values from database but I am not able to do that.I am using mysql database named as travel and table is also named as travel.I am attaching my python code and template below
My error is:werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'stay'

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect,flash,url_for,session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import datetime
import time
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = "127.1.1.0"
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = "root"
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = "****"
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] ="travel"
app.secret_key="gsabo"
mysql = MySQL(app)
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/questions',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def questions():
    if request.method == "POST" or "GET":
        userDetails= request.form
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        stay=userDetails['stay']
        Budget=userDetails['Budget']
        print(Passengers,Weather,Transport,stay,Interests)
        cur.execute("select * from travel where stay=%s,Budget=%s",(stay,Budget,))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        userDetails=cur.fetchone()
        Location=userDetails[3]
        Budget=userDetails[4]
        return render_template('questions.html',Budget=Budget,Location=Location)
    return render_template('questions.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Template in HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Travel</title>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<form action="/questions" method="post"> 
<table>
            <tr><th colspan="2">Find Travel Detination and Budget</th></tr>
                <tr>  
                    <td> stay<font color='red'>*</font> :</td>  
                    <td><select name="stay">
                        <option>Select</option>
            <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
            <option value="Tent">Tent</option>
            </select></td>  
                </tr>  


                <tr>  
                    <td>Budget<font color='red'>*</font> :</td>  
                    <td><select name="Budget">
                        <option>Select</option>
            <option value="1000">1000$</option>
            <option value="2000">2000$</option>
            <option value="3000">3000$</option>
            <option value="4000">4000$</option>
            <option value="5000">5000$</option>
            <option value="6000">6000$</option>
            <option value="7000">7000$</option>
            <option value="8000">8000$</option>
            <option value="9000">9000$</option>
            <option value="10000">10000$</option>
            </select></td>  
                </tr>

                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" href="hello" /></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>  
                </tr>  
        <tr>  
                    <td>Budget:</td>  
                    <td><input type="number" name="Budget" value="<%=Budget %>" readonly disabled/></td>  
                </tr> 
                <tr>  
                    <td>Location:</td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="Location" value="<%=Location %>" readonly disabled/></td>  
                </tr>  
</form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if request.method == "POST" or "GET":` is always True because it is like `if (request.method == "POST") or ("GET"):` and "GET" and all other non-empty strings have True boolean value

Comment: @VPfB So what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><select name="stay">
                        <option>Select</option>
            <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
            <option value="Tent">Tent</option>
            </select></td>
```

You have this code block, presumably you can POST to /questions with `value = "Hotel"` or `value = "Tent"`, but in code only accounting for `value = "stay"`.  You need to account for every case

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The same way that you assigned the value from `userDetails['stay']`.